# check if a file contains two variables in a line

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am trying to check the values of my variables are exist in the file or not using if condition in Bash.
I tried is as follows, but for all the values I am getting value false.

```
a=-127.5256
b=24.5632

file=test.txt
-54.2565   58.9685
-127.2568  12.5890
-127.5256  24.5632
-78.9865   35.2366
```

I tried as follow but not working in my case:

```
if grep -Fxq "($a $b | bc)" $file; then
  echo True
else
  echo False
```

Is there any other way to perform the above job?

Thank you

Comment: define value in this case.

Comment: But values of my varaibles (a & b) varies with the iteration.

Comment: What is `bc` suppose to do there? If you do `($a $b | bc)` what do you expect to see? I mean what is the output you're expecting?

Comment: I used "bc" to read the float values of the variables.  Can it be a $(bc <<< "$a $b)"?

Comment: What is value? what do you mean by value? what is `bc` doing there? `echo "$a" "$b"` will show you the value of the variables `"$a"` and `"$b"`, Now again what is bc doing there?

Comment: value means the number assign to the variable. In my case a=-127.5256 and b=24.5632

Comment: @PiyushkumarPatel: You have in your file two spaces between 127.5256 and 24.5632, but you grep for one space.

Comment: @PiyushkumarPatel : In addition, if you are using extended regular expressions (as we can see from your construct `(...|...)`, you have to supply the `-E` option to grep instead of `-F`. The way you wrote it, grep searches for a literal open parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use AWK.

`awk -v a=-127.5256 -v b=24.5632 '{if ($1==a && $2=b) print "True"}' < input file`

using bash

```
while IFS=" " read -r f1 f2; 
do  
if [ "$a" == "$f1" ] && [ "$b" == "$f2" ]
then 
echo "True"
fi 
done < input file
```

Demo:

```
$cat test.txt 
-54.2565   58.9685
-127.2568  12.5890
-127.5256  24.5632
-78.9865   35.2366
$awk -v a=-127.5256 -v b=24.5632 '{if ($1==a && $2=b) print "True"}' test.txt
True
$echo $a $b
-127.5256 24.5632
$while IFS=" " read -r f1 f2; 
> do  
> if [ "$a" == "$f1" ] && [ "$b" == "$f2" ]
> then 
> echo "True"
> fi 
> done < test.txt
True
$
```